# Jar file not identifying - Maven artifact missing

Tags: java, maven

The Dependency:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
       <artifactId>ibatis-common</artifactId>
       <version>2.0</version>
       <scope>main</scope>  
   </dependency>
```

and I am getting the following error. It says: `Unable to find resource 'org.apache.ibatis:ibatis-common:jar:2.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)`
So I tried to install it using the command but still I am getting the following error.
Can any body help me out?

### Missing:

```
1) org.apache.ibatis:ibatis-common:jar:2.0

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.ibatis -DartifactId=ibatis-common -Dversion=2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.ibatis -DartifactId=ibatis-common -Dversion=2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) sonatype:Struts2OfficeExpenses:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    2) org.apache.ibatis:ibatis-common:jar:2.0

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  sonatype:Struts2OfficeExpenses:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

Comment: what command did you issue to try to install it manually?

Comment: 'mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.ibatis -DartifactId=ibatis-common -Dversion=2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file'

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the dependency you have specified is not found by maven.
You can specify the repository to get the jars.

### add the dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibatis</groupId>
  <artifactId>ibatis2-common</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.7.597</version>
</dependency>
```

### add the repository

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
    <id>appfuse-releases</id>
    <name>AppFuse Releases</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse-releases</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hemant But i am getting the same error again since in the mirror the required jar file is not there i need ibatis-common but there we have ibatis2-common

Comment: i have replaced dependancy and repository please check it

Comment: Perhaps the group and artifact id are wrong. A quick search at http://search.maven.org has lead to this: <groupId>com.ibatis</groupId>
<artifactId>ibatis-common</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0.565</version>

Comment: 'ibatis2-common' does not support my project i need ibatis-common jar file only   even though i have tried the modified dependency so i got many java errors

Comment: use this repository http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/browse/com/ibatis/ibatis-common/1.3.1/?by=numDir&order=des&d=y

Comment: Hey the lower end versions are not supported by the project and also 2.1.0.565 version is also not working

Comment: Hi Hemant i could not solve my issue yet .. even after installing manually i am able to see only the jar file but not the source file (sources.jar)

Comment: why do you need to see sorce file? binary jar does not contain source but contains the compiled binary code so you will be able to call its functions.

Comment: Ya i can use the functions but my question is even after installing manually into the local repository, i am getting the same error.

Comment: then check for the function which is not found does the jar serves your purpose ? else move to a jar containing that method.